# Having issues compiling my brownie_fund_me

Tags: contract-deployment, brownie

Received this error while trying to compile, codes are exactly the same. CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

```
contracts/FundMe.sol:8:1: ParserError: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
^--------------------------------------------------------------------------^

contracts/FundMe.sol:9:1: ParserError: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";
^------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Here is my brownie-config.yaml
dependencies:

```
- <organization/repo>@
smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
solc:
remappings:
'@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
```

Here's the code.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

// Smart contract that lets anyone deposit ETH into the contract
// Only the owner of the contract can withdraw the ETH
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;
// Get the latest ETH/USD price from chainlink price feed

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

contract FundMe {
// safe math library check uint256 for integer overflows
using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;

//mapping to store which address deposited how much ETH
mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
// array of addresses who deposited
address[] public funders;
//address of the owner (who deployed the contract)
address public owner;

// the first person to deploy the contract is
// the owner
constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function fund() public payable {
    // 18 digit number to be compared with donated amount
    uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10**18;
    //is the donated amount less than 50USD?
    require(
        getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD,
        "You need to spend more ETH!"
    );
    //if not, add to mapping and funders array
    addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    funders.push(msg.sender);
}

//function to get the version of the chainlink pricefeed
function getVersion() public view returns (uint256) {
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
        0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e
    );
    return priceFeed.version();
}

function getPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
        0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e
    );
    (, int256 answer, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    // ETH/USD rate in 18 digit
    return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
}

// 1000000000
function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount)
    public
    view
    returns (uint256)
{
    uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
    uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1000000000000000000;
    // the actual ETH/USD conversation rate, after adjusting the extra 0s.
    return ethAmountInUsd;
}

//modifier: https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-tutorial-all-about-modifiers-a86cf81c14cb
modifier onlyOwner() {
    //is the message sender owner of the contract?
    require(msg.sender == owner);

    _;
}

// onlyOwner modifer will first check the condition inside it
// and
// if true, withdraw function will be executed
function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
    // If you are using version eight (v0.8) of chainlink aggregator interface,
    // you will need to change the code below to
    // payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
    msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);

    //iterate through all the mappings and make them 0
    //since all the deposited amount has been withdrawn
    for (
        uint256 funderIndex = 0;
        funderIndex < funders.length;
        funderIndex++
    ) {
        address funder = funders[funderIndex];
        addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
    }
    //funders array will be initialized to 0
    funders = new address[](0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add them to your brownie-config.yaml?

If not it should look like this:

```
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.1'
dotenv: .env
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```